# When to use multivariable chain rule in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, ideal-gas

If I take $U(P,V)$, I can do:
$$ \frac{dU}{dT} =  \frac{\partial U }{\partial P } \frac{dP}{dT}+\frac{\partial U }{\partial V} \frac{dV}{dT}   \tag1$$

But,  I see the following used in books,
$ dU = zPdV + zVdP $

Thinking $$U= zPV \tag 2$$  for ideal gas.

So,
$$\frac{dU}{dT} = zp\frac{dV}{dT}+ zV\frac{dP}{dT} \tag3$$

Are both statements $(1)$ & $(3)$ equivalent?
Is the equation $(2)$ correct for all ideal situations?

Answer (score 1):

The exterior derivative of a function is defined as:

$${\displaystyle d\omega =\sum _{i=1}^{n}{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}}\,dx_{i}.}$$

In your equation $(1)$ you can just multiply both sides with $\frac{1}{T}$ and get the same equation, you just happen to chose the $p$ and $V$ variables. So you don't really need to use the multivariable chain rule.

Usually, in thermodynamics we want to expand functions in this way, as to see on what variables they depend.

We do this for the internal energy $U$ with the variables $T$ and $V$ as it has interesting results:

$$dU(T,V)=\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\,dT + \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \,dV.$$

You can prove that for the ideal gas the internal energy $U$ doesn't depend on anything else but the temperature $T$, or just look up [Joules second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect#Joule.27s_second_law).

By defining the specific heat capacity for a process where there is no change in volume as $$c_V = \frac{1}{m} \left({\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}}\right)_V$$

you get that

$$dU=m\,c_V\, dT$$

for an ideal gas.

So your equation $(2)$ doesn't seem correct to me, but I am not sure what the $z$ variable represents. A better way to calculate the $dU$ for an ideal gas is the equation I provided.

And yes, the equations $(1)$ and $(3)$ are mathematically equivalent, you just differentiated partially your equation $(2)$ and inputed the result in $(3)$.

Comment: Z is proportional to degree of freedom here of an ideal gas.  I took it as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm teaching this material now. I think your approach has a serious misconception. If we have $U=z PV$ with $z$ constant it is indeed safe to say that $d U = z P d V + z V d P$. However, in standard fluid thermodynamics, one cannot calculate a quantity like

$$\frac{d U}{d T}$$

because such a quantity is undefined. Because there are two ways of changing the energy of the system (doing work on it or adding heat to it) then state space represents a two-dimensional surface in $(S,T,P,V,U,\ldots)$ space. A quantity like

$$\frac{d U}{d T}$$

is the ratio of a small change of energy to a small change of temperature. But this ratio is actually different depending on which direction one moves on this two dimensional surface. Instead, in thermodynamics one typically calculates quantities such as

$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V, \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_P,$$

which refer respectively to the ratio of change in energy to change in temperature in the direction in which either volume $V$ or pressure $P$ is held constant. In general these will be different.

Once one has such a properly defined partial derivative, one can indeed obtain the multivariable chain rule, or perform other calculations. For example, one could return to the above expression,

$$d U = z P d V + z V d P$$

and choose to ask about the changes as one changes pressure $P$ and holds temperature $T$ constant. The result is:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right)_T = z P \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_T + z V$$